# Javascript: I have a grid of empty div squares I need mouse events to change the color of each div when I mouse over them

Tags: javascript

I have a grid of empty div squares and I want to create a function that allows the user to click and drag the mouse over the divs, which will effectively change the colors of the divs that they click and drag over. Which mouse events should I use?

Answer (score 0):

There's great example at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag).

I pasted it in at JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/e9c90esg/

There are used `dragstart`, `dragend`, `dragover`, `drop`, `dragleave` events.